# C# equivalent of C sscanf

Tags: c#, c, string, formatted-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent to 'sscanf()' in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492262/is-there-an-equivalent-to-sscanf-in-net)

sscanf in C is a nice way to read well formatted input from a string.

How to achieve this C#.

For example,

```
int a,b;
char *str= "10 12";
sscanf(str,"%d %d",&a,&b);
```

The above code will assign 10 to a and 12 to b.

How to achieve the same using C#?

Comment: And some people at Microsoft think `C#` is better than `C++` ... **`(~.~)`**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in C#. Given the same task in C#, you could do it something like this:

```
string str = "10 12";
var parts = str.Split(' ');
int a = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
int b = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
```

Depending on how well-formed you can assume the input to be, you might want to add some error checks.

Comment: I am aware of this technique already. It would have been nice though to have something like sscanf in C#.

Comment: @Gunner, I agree it would be nice. But I think you would have to implement it yourself, if you need it. It doesn't exist in the framework.

Comment: downvote; this is a ridiculous answer. sscanf is vastly more complex than simply splitting on a common delimiter. For example, "%d%3s%d" should resolve "123abc567" to 123, abc, 567, which is something that split cannot be used for.

Comment: @Doug, I am well aware that sscanf is a different beast from `Split`, hence I start the answer by "There is no direct equivalent" -> And then I give an example on how the concrete task mentioned by the OP can be accomplished in C#.

Answer (score 11):

There is no direct equivalent of `sscanf` in the .NET Framework.

The simplest way to achieve the same functionality is splitting the string ([`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)) and then assigning the subsequent parts to variables with the [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) method. For example:

```
string myString = "10, 12";
string[] stringValues = myString.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int a = Int32.Parse(stringValues[0]);
int b = Int32.Parse(stringValues[1]);
```

Many different data types in the Framework have `Parse` methods, including enumerations, if the values you want to read in from the string are not necessarily integer values.

You could also use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx), but they're probably a bit overkill for a task as simple as this.

**EDIT:** If you're truly deadset on using `sscanf`, you could always consider P/Invoking the function from the C runtime libraries. Something like this perhaps (untested):

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int sscanf(string buffer, string format, ref int arg0, ref int arg1);
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm just writing to kill time.

```
public static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a, b,c;
    string str = "10 12 100";
    sscanf(str, ' ', &a, &b, &c);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", a, b, c);
    Console.Read();
}

public static unsafe void sscanf(string str, char seperator, params int*[] targets)
{
    var parts = str.Split(seperator);
    if (parts.Length != targets.Length) throw new ArgumentException();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        *targets[i] = int.Parse(parts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i know you are just killing time. BUT your code is rockin! (very concise, very readable, very flexible --> equals rockin!)

Comment: i bet some people weren't up voting because of the "unsafe" thing. i am pretty sure most c# developers are not allowed to use the "unsafe" keyword. i am a very "c" centric developer so... no biggie there.

Comment: or just because it is only a part of sscanf functionality ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Writing your own `sscanf()` method in C# isn't that difficult, if you don't mind writing a little low-level code.

You can see my version in the article [A sscanf() Replacement for .NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net).

Comment: it seems to fail to parse this format: "%[0-9]/%[0-9]/%[0-9]"

Answer (score 1):

from [Run-Time Routines and .NET Framework Equivalents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms395663%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> sscanf, swscanf ==> See Parse methods, such as [System.Double.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse(v=VS.71).aspx)

So, I guess there's no direct equivalent.